# Как побороть ошибку при заполнении поиска плагина shuffle.js

Tags: javascript

Сделал по примеру [shuffle.js](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/)  свою сортировку, фильтрацию и поиск, результат:

```js
var Shuffle = window.Shuffle;

var Demo = function(element) {
  this.element = element;

  this.shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
    itemSelector: '.product-item',
    sizer: element.querySelector('.my-sizer-element'),
  });

  // Log events.
  this.addShuffleEventListeners();

  this._activeFilters = [];

  this.addFilterButtons();
  this.addSorting();
  this.addSearchFilter();

  this.mode = 'exclusive';
};

Demo.prototype.toggleMode = function() {
  if (this.mode === 'additive') {
    this.mode = 'exclusive';
  } else {
    this.mode = 'additive';
  }
};

/**
 * Shuffle uses the CustomEvent constructor to dispatch events. You can listen
 * for them like you normally would (with jQuery for example).
 */
Demo.prototype.addShuffleEventListeners = function() {
  this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, function(data) {
    console.log('layout. data:', data);
  });

  this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.REMOVED, function(data) {
    console.log('removed. data:', data);
  });
};

Demo.prototype.addFilterButtons = function() {
  var options = document.querySelector('.filter-options');

  if (!options) {
    return;
  }

  var filterButtons = Array.from(options.children);

  filterButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', this._handleFilterClick.bind(this), false);
  }, this);
};

Demo.prototype._handleFilterClick = function(evt) {
  var btn = evt.currentTarget;
  var isActive = btn.classList.contains('active');
  var btnGroup = btn.getAttribute('data-group');


  Demo.prototype.addShuffleEventListeners = function() {
    this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, function(data) {
      console.log('layout. data:', data);
    });

    this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.REMOVED, function(data) {
      console.log('removed. data:', data);
    });
  };

  // You don't need _both_ of these modes. This is only for the demo.

  // For this custom 'additive' mode in the demo, clicking on filter buttons
  // doesn't remove any other filters.
  if (this.mode === 'additive') {
    // If this button is already active, remove it from the list of filters.
    if (isActive) {
      this._activeFilters.splice(this._activeFilters.indexOf(btnGroup));
    } else {
      this._activeFilters.push(btnGroup);
    }

    btn.classList.toggle('active');

    // Filter elements
    this.shuffle.filter(this._activeFilters);

    // 'exclusive' mode lets only one filter button be active at a time.
  } else {
    this._removeActiveClassFromChildren(btn.parentNode);

    var filterGroup;
    if (isActive) {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
      filterGroup = Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS;
    } else {
      btn.classList.add('active');
      filterGroup = btnGroup;
    }

    this.shuffle.filter(filterGroup);
  }
};

Demo.prototype._removeActiveClassFromChildren = function(parent) {
  var children = parent.children;
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    children[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
};

Demo.prototype.addSorting = function() {
  var buttonGroup = document.querySelector('.sort-options');

  if (!buttonGroup) {
    return;
  }

  buttonGroup.addEventListener('change', this._handleSortChange.bind(this));
};

Demo.prototype._handleSortChange = function(evt) {
  // Add and remove `active` class from buttons.
  var wrapper = evt.currentTarget;
  var buttons = Array.from(evt.currentTarget.children);
  buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    if (button.querySelector('input').value === evt.target.value) {
      button.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      button.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });

  // Create the sort options to give to Shuffle.
  var value = evt.target.value;
  var options = {};

  function sortByDate(element) {
    return element.getAttribute('data-created');
  }

  function sortByTitle(element) {
    return element.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase();
  }

  if (value === 'date-created') {
    options = {
      reverse: true,
      by: sortByDate,
    };
  } else if (value === 'title') {
    options = {
      by: sortByTitle,
    };
  }

  this.shuffle.sort(options);
};

// Advanced filtering
Demo.prototype.addSearchFilter = function() {
  var searchInput = document.querySelector('.js-shuffle-search');

  if (!searchInput) {
    return;
  }

  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', this._handleSearchKeyup.bind(this));
};

/**
 * Filter the shuffle instance by items with a title that matches the search input.
 * @param {Event} evt Event object.
 */
Demo.prototype._handleSearchKeyup = function(evt) {
  var searchText = evt.target.value.toLowerCase();

  this.shuffle.filter(function(element, shuffle) {

    // If there is a current filter applied, ignore elements that don't match it.
    if (shuffle.group !== Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS) {
      // Get the item's groups.
      var groups = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-groups'));
      var isElementInCurrentGroup = groups.indexOf(shuffle.group) !== -1;

      // Only search elements in the current group
      if (!isElementInCurrentGroup) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    var titleElement = element.querySelector('.title');
    var titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();

    return titleText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
  });
};
window.demo = new Demo(document.getElementById('grid'));
```

```css
   
.row {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.row:after,
.row:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table
}

.row:after {
  clear: both
}

.row .row {
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px
}

.row--centered {
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center
}

.aspect {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.col-1\@lg,
.col-1\@md,
.col-1\@sm,
.col-1\@xs,
.col-2\@lg,
.col-2\@md,
.col-2\@sm,
.col-2\@xs,
.col-3\@lg,
.col-3\@md,
.col-3\@sm,
.col-3\@xs,
.col-4\@lg,
.col-4\@md,
.col-4\@sm,
.col-4\@xs,
.col-5\@lg,
.col-5\@md,
.col-5\@sm,
.col-5\@xs,
.col-6\@lg,
.col-6\@md,
.col-6\@sm,
.col-6\@xs,
.col-7\@lg,
.col-7\@md,
.col-7\@sm,
.col-7\@xs,
.col-8\@lg,
.col-8\@md,
.col-8\@sm,
.col-8\@xs,
.col-9\@lg,
.col-9\@md,
.col-9\@sm,
.col-9\@xs,
.col-10\@lg,
.col-10\@md,
.col-10\@sm,
.col-10\@xs,
.col-11\@lg,
.col-11\@md,
.col-11\@sm,
.col-11\@xs,
.col-12\@lg,
.col-12\@md,
.col-12\@sm,
.col-12\@xs {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  position: relative
}

.col-1\@xs,
.col-2\@xs,
.col-3\@xs,
.col-4\@xs,
.col-5\@xs,
.col-6\@xs,
.col-7\@xs,
.col-8\@xs,
.col-9\@xs,
.col-10\@xs,
.col-11\@xs,
.col-12\@xs {
  float: left
}

.col-1\@xs {
  width: 16.66667%
}

.col-2\@xs {
  width: 33.33333%
}

.col-3\@xs {
  width: 50%
}

.col-4\@xs {
  width: 66.66667%
}

.col-5\@xs {
  width: 83.33333%
}

.col-6\@xs {
  width: 100%
}

.col-pull-0\@xs {
  right: auto
}

.col-pull-1\@xs {
  right: 16.66667%
}

.col-pull-2\@xs {
  right: 33.33333%
}

.col-pull-3\@xs {
  right: 50%
}

.col-pull-4\@xs {
  right: 66.66667%
}

.col-pull-5\@xs {
  right: 83.33333%
}

.col-pull-6\@xs {
  right: 100%
}

.col-push-0\@xs {
  left: auto
}

.col-push-1\@xs {
  left: 16.66667%
}

.col-push-2\@xs {
  left: 33.33333%
}

.col-push-3\@xs {
  left: 50%
}

.col-push-4\@xs {
  left: 66.66667%
}

.col-push-5\@xs {
  left: 83.33333%
}

.col-push-6\@xs {
  left: 100%
}

.col-offset-0\@xs {
  margin-left: 0
}

.col-offset-1\@xs {
  margin-left: 16.66667%
}

.col-offset-2\@xs {
  margin-left: 33.33333%
}

.col-offset-3\@xs {
  margin-left: 50%
}

.col-offset-4\@xs {
  margin-left: 66.66667%
}

.col-offset-5\@xs {
  margin-left: 83.33333%
}

.col-offset-6\@xs {
  margin-left: 100%
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .col-1\@sm,
  .col-2\@sm,
  .col-3\@sm,
  .col-4\@sm,
  .col-5\@sm,
  .col-6\@sm,
  .col-7\@sm,
  .col-8\@sm,
  .col-9\@sm,
  .col-10\@sm,
  .col-11\@sm,
  .col-12\@sm {
    float: left
  }
 
  .col-1\@sm {
    width: 8.33333%
  }
  .col-2\@sm {
    width: 16.66667%
  }
  .col-3\@sm {
    width: 25%
  }
  .col-4\@sm {
    width: 33.33333%
  }
  .col-5\@sm {
    width: 41.66667%
  }
  .col-6\@sm {
    width: 50%
  }
  .col-7\@sm {
    width: 58.33333%
  }
  .col-8\@sm {
    width: 66.66667%
  }
  .col-9\@sm {
    width: 75%
  }
  .col-10\@sm {
    width: 83.33333%
  }
  .col-11\@sm {
    width: 91.66667%
  }
  .col-12\@sm {
    width: 100%
  }
  .col-pull-0\@sm {
    right: auto
  }
  .col-pull-1\@sm {
    right: 8.33333%
  }
  .col-pull-2\@sm {
    right: 16.66667%
  }
  .col-pull-3\@sm {
    right: 25%
  }
  .col-pull-4\@sm {
    right: 33.33333%
  }
  .col-pull-5\@sm {
    right: 41.66667%
  }
  .col-pull-6\@sm {
    right: 50%
  }
  .col-pull-7\@sm {
    right: 58.33333%
  }
  .col-pull-8\@sm {
    right: 66.66667%
  }
  .col-pull-9\@sm {
    right: 75%
  }
  .col-pull-10\@sm {
    right: 83.33333%
  }
  .col-pull-11\@sm {
    right: 91.66667%
  }
  .col-pull-12\@sm {
    right: 100%
  }
  .col-push-0\@sm {
    left: auto
  }
  .col-push-1\@sm {
    left: 8.33333%
  }
  .col-push-2\@sm {
    left: 16.66667%
  }
  .col-push-3\@sm {
    left: 25%
  }
  .col-push-4\@sm {
    left: 33.33333%
  }
  .col-push-5\@sm {
    left: 41.66667%
  }
  .col-push-6\@sm {
    left: 50%
  }
  .col-push-7\@sm {
    left: 58.33333%
  }
  .col-push-8\@sm {
    left: 66.66667%
  }
  .col-push-9\@sm {
    left: 75%
  }
  .col-push-10\@sm {
    left: 83.33333%
  }
  .col-push-11\@sm {
    left: 91.66667%
  }
  .col-push-12\@sm {
    left: 100%
  }
  .col-offset-0\@sm {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .col-offset-1\@sm {
    margin-left: 8.33333%
  }
  .col-offset-2\@sm {
    margin-left: 16.66667%
  }
  .col-offset-3\@sm {
    margin-left: 25%
  }
  .col-offset-4\@sm {
    margin-left: 33.33333%
  }
  .col-offset-5\@sm {
    margin-left: 41.66667%
  }
  .col-offset-6\@sm {
    margin-left: 50%
  }
  .col-offset-7\@sm {
    margin-left: 58.33333%
  }
  .col-offset-8\@sm {
    margin-left: 66.66667%
  }
  .col-offset-9\@sm {
    margin-left: 75%
  }
  .col-offset-10\@sm {
    margin-left: 83.33333%
  }
  .col-offset-11\@sm {
    margin-left: 91.66667%
  }
  .col-offset-12\@sm {
    margin-left: 100%
  }
  .container {
    padding-left: 7%;
    padding-right: 7%
  }
  .row {
    max-width: 1200px
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
  .col-1\@md,
  .col-2\@md,
  .col-3\@md,
  .col-4\@md,
  .col-5\@md,
  .col-6\@md,
  .col-7\@md,
  .col-8\@md,
  .col-9\@md,
  .col-10\@md,
  .col-11\@md,
  .col-12\@md {
    float: left
  }
 
  .col-1\@md {
    width: 8.33333%
  }
  .col-2\@md {
    width: 16.66667%
  }
  .col-3\@md {
    width: 25%
  }
  .col-4\@md {
    width: 33.33333%
  }
  .col-5\@md {
    width: 41.66667%
  }
  .col-6\@md {
    width: 50%
  }
  .col-7\@md {
    width: 58.33333%
  }
  .col-8\@md {
    width: 66.66667%
  }
  .col-9\@md {
    width: 75%
  }
  .col-10\@md {
    width: 83.33333%
  }
  .col-11\@md {
    width: 91.66667%
  }
  .col-12\@md {
    width: 100%
  }
  .col-pull-0\@md {
    right: auto
  }
  .col-pull-1\@md {
    right: 8.33333%
  }
  .col-pull-2\@md {
    right: 16.66667%
  }
  .col-pull-3\@md {
    right: 25%
  }
  .col-pull-4\@md {
    right: 33.33333%
  }
  .col-pull-5\@md {
    right: 41.66667%
  }
  .col-pull-6\@md {
    right: 50%
  }
  .col-pull-7\@md {
    right: 58.33333%
  }
  .col-pull-8\@md {
    right: 66.66667%
  }
  .col-pull-9\@md {
    right: 75%
  }
  .col-pull-10\@md {
    right: 83.33333%
  }
  .col-pull-11\@md {
    right: 91.66667%
  }
  .col-pull-12\@md {
    right: 100%
  }
  .col-push-0\@md {
    left: auto
  }
  .col-push-1\@md {
    left: 8.33333%
  }
  .col-push-2\@md {
    left: 16.66667%
  }
  .col-push-3\@md {
    left: 25%
  }
  .col-push-4\@md {
    left: 33.33333%
  }
  .col-push-5\@md {
    left: 41.66667%
  }
  .col-push-6\@md {
    left: 50%
  }
  .col-push-7\@md {
    left: 58.33333%
  }
  .col-push-8\@md {
    left: 66.66667%
  }
  .col-push-9\@md {
    left: 75%
  }
  .col-push-10\@md {
    left: 83.33333%
  }
  .col-push-11\@md {
    left: 91.66667%
  }
  .col-push-12\@md {
    left: 100%
  }
  .col-offset-0\@md {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .col-offset-1\@md {
    margin-left: 8.33333%
  }
  .col-offset-2\@md {
    margin-left: 16.66667%
  }
  .col-offset-3\@md {
    margin-left: 25%
  }
  .col-offset-4\@md {
    margin-left: 33.33333%
  }
  .col-offset-5\@md {
    margin-left: 41.66667%
  }
  .col-offset-6\@md {
    margin-left: 50%
  }
  .col-offset-7\@md {
    margin-left: 58.33333%
  }
  .col-offset-8\@md {
    margin-left: 66.66667%
  }
  .col-offset-9\@md {
    margin-left: 75%
  }
  .col-offset-10\@md {
    margin-left: 83.33333%
  }
  .col-offset-11\@md {
    margin-left: 91.66667%
  }
  .col-offset-12\@md {
    margin-left: 100%
  }
}

.textfield {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 2px solid #95a5a6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #34495e;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: .5em;
  transition: .15s;
  width: 100%
}

.btn {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: rgba(52, 73, 94, 0);
  border: 1px solid #34495e;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #34495e;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

.btn.active:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
}

.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: -4px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.filter-label {
  color: #95a5a6;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0
}

.filter-label,
.filters-group {
  margin-bottom: 4px
}

-------------------------------shuffle css-------------------- .product-item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product-item__inner {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.product-item__inner span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.product-item__details {
  -ms-flex-align: baseline;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-box-align: baseline;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  align-items: baseline;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-item__title {
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 4px
}

.product-item__tags {
  -ms-flex-negative: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .product-item--overlay .product-item__details {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
  }
  .product-item--overlay .product-item__description {
    display: none
  }
  @supports ((-webkit-filter:blur(1px)) or (filter:blur(1px))) and ((-webkit-clip-path:inset(0 0 0 0)) or (clip-path:inset(0 0 0 0))) {
    .product-item--overlay .product-item__blur {
      -webkit-clip-path: inset(170px 0 0 0);
      -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
      clip-path: inset(170px 0 0 0);
      display: block;
      filter: blur(7px);
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1
    }
    .product-item--overlay .pproduct-item__details {
      background: none
    }
    .product-item--overlay .product-item__tags,
    .product-item--overlay .product-item__title {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2
    }
  }
}

.my-shuffle-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.my-sizer-element {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden
}

.shuffle--animatein {
  overflow: visible
}

.shuffle--animatein .product-item__inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(220px);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(220px)
}

.shuffle--animatein .product-item__inner--transition {
  transition: all .6s ease
}

.shuffle--animatein .product-item.in .product-item__inner {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0)
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .product-item {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px
  }
  .product-item__description,
  .product-item__details {
    font-size: .875em;
    padding: .625em
  }
  .product-item__description {
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
    padding-right: .875em
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Shuffle/5.0.2/shuffle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="Demo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4@sm col-3@md filters-group">
        <label for="filters-search-input" class="filter-label">Search</label>
        <input class="textfield filter__search js-shuffle-search" type="search" id="filters-search-input" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12@sm filters-group-wrap">
        <div class="filters-group">
          <p class="filter-label">Filter</p>
          <div class="btn-group filter-options">
            <button class="btn" data-group="fr"><span>FR</span></button>
            <button class="btn" data-group="de"><span>DE</span></button>
            <button class="btn" data-group="es"><span>ES</span></button>
            <button class="btn" data-group="it"><span>IT</span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filters-group">
          <p class="filter-label">Sort</p>
          <div class="sort-options">
            <label class="active">
              <input type="radio" name="sort-value" value="dom" /> Default
            </label>
            <label class="">
              <input type="radio" name="sort-value" value="title" /> Title
            </label>
            <label class="">
              <input type="radio" name="sort-value" value="date-created" /> Date Created
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="grid" class="row my-shuffle-container">

        <figure class="col-3@xs col-4@sm col-3@md product-item" data-groups='["de"]' data-status="moderation" data-date-created="2015-07-23" data-title="Product4">
          <span class="title">Product4</span>
          <div class="product-item__inner">
            <div class="aspect">
              <span class="country">DE</span>
              <span class="date">2016-07-23</span>
              <span class="status">moderation</span>

            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>


        <figure class="col-3@xs col-4@sm col-3@md product-item" data-groups='["de"]' data-status="finished" data-date-created="2016-08-12" data-title="Product1">
          <div class="product-item__inner">
            <div class="aspect">
              <span class="country">DE</span>
              <span class="date">2016-08-12</span>
              <span class="status">finished</span>
              <span class="title">Product1</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>

        <figure class="col-3@xs col-4@sm col-3@md product-item" data-groups='["it"]' data-status="active" data-date-created="2016-03-07" data-title="Product2">
          <div class="product-item__inner">
            <div class="aspect">
              <span class="country">IT</span>
              <span class="date">2016-03-07</span>
              <span class="status">active</span>
              <span class="title">Product2</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>

        <figure class="col-3@xs col-4@sm col-3@md product-item" data-groups='["es"]' data-status="active" data-date-created="2016-06-09" data-title="Product3">
          <div class="product-item__inner">
            <div class="aspect">
              <span class="country">ES</span>
              <span class="date">2016-06-09</span>
              <span class="status">active</span>
              <span class="title">Product3</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>



        <figure class="col-3@xs col-4@sm col-3@md product-item" data-groups='["it"]' data-status="draft" data-date-created="2014-10-12" data-title="Product5">
          <div class="product-item__inner">
            <div class="aspect">
              <span class="country">IT</span>
              <span class="date">2014-10-12</span>
              <span class="status">draft</span>
              <span class="title">Product5</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>

        <figure class="col-3@xs col-4@sm col-3@md product-item" data-groups='["de"]' data-status="active" data-date-created="2015-10-20" data-title="Product7">
          <div class="product-item__inner">
            <div class="aspect">
              <span class="country">DE</span>
              <span class="date">2015-10-20</span>
              <span class="status">active</span>
              <span class="title">Product7</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>

        <figure class="col-3@xs col-4@sm col-3@md product-item" data-groups='["fr"]' data-status="finished" data-date-created="2017-01-12" data-title="Product6">
          <div class="product-item__inner">
            <div class="aspect">
              <span class="country">FR</span>
              <span class="date">2017-01-12</span>
              <span class="status">finished</span>
              <span class="title">Product6</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>

        <div class="col-1@sm col-1@xs my-sizer-element"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

но когда все перенес на рабочий сайт, то поиск перестал работать, и в консоли появилась ошибка:

```
script.js:205 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (script.js:205)
at e.value (vendor.js:6266)
at vendor.js:6266
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at e.value (vendor.js:6266)
at e.value (vendor.js:6266)
at e.value (vendor.js:6266)
at Demo._handleSearchKeyup (script.js:190)
```

с ссылкой на вот эту строку: 
**var titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();**

Не могу понять в чем проблема,почему возникает ошибка? 
В фиддле и тут все работает. Помогите разобраться с проблемой. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в последней карточке продукта, в которой указаны пустые дата-атрибуты, все решилось простой заменой класса карточки (исключения пустых дата-атрибутов для фильтра)

```
<div class="col-3@xs col-4@sm col-3@md col-2@lg product-item-inner" data-groups='[""]' data-status="" data-date-created="" data-title="">
            <img class="transform-x-y" src="{% static 'jl/cd/img/plus.png' %}" alt="plus">
        </div>
```